# Parse Log Message using Java

Tags: java, parsing, logging

I have a log message something like this

```
[6/15/18 20:26:27:798 IST] 00000031 SystemOut     O 20:26:27 18-06-15 20:26:27.797 debug {JPA Server-jpaserver.helloworld.com} Invoke HelloWorld.findByKey(Parameter) takes 89 ms
```

I want to parse this log to fetch information such as Timestamp, Action, etc. Is there any library available in Java which can return me such values with log message as an input?

Comment: Questions asking for library recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow. There are plenty of parsing libraries available. Google is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use a library.

It appears that the log data is separated by spaces so you can use String.split as shown below:

```
String[] parsed = logDataString.split(" ");
```

Then you can use more parsing such as concatenating the last four elements of the array.